# how to solve problem of that IO thread in slave cannot read the correct position in master in mariadb 10.3 ? I tried to use GTID_based replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb-10.3, gtid

I have a problem when using new style GTID_based replication on mariadb 10.3 in case of multi master and slaves replication ..I  cannot use auto positioning in case of the IO thread in slave cannot find the correct file position in master server (in case of that slave has multiple master servers.
we can do that task with one master server and it works good but we cannot make it work for multiple servers .

I used this statements to change the replication from old way to GTId

stop all slaves;

CHANGE MASTER 'serverABC' TO MASTER_HOST = '123.123.123.123', MASTER_USER = 'db_user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password', master_use_gtid=slave_pos;

START ALL SLAVES;

I try to do changes in  my database in master server and it reflects well in slave

after that I changed master to wrong file position

stop all slaves;

CHANGE MASTER 'serverABC' TO MASTER_HOST = '123.123.123.123', MASTER_USER = 'db_user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000106', MASTER_LOG_POS =11011110 ;
START ALL SLAVES;

this gave me IO thread error

then I

START ALL SLAVES;

CHANGE MASTER 'serverABC' TO MASTER_HOST = '123.123.123.123', MASTER_USER = 'db_user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password', master_use_gtid=slave_pos;

stop all slaves;

the Io thread worked fine
when I make changes in my database in master server and it reflects well in slave

.........

but my problem appeared when their is multi masters and slave
when I change slave to wrong file position and use gtid again the Io thread doesn't work and cannot use the auto positioning .